# Mostrar diferentes controladores en el mapa

Tags: gvnix

Tengo una entidad `Actuaciones`, con su controlador, y he creado un nuevo controlador `Electricidad`:

```
web mvc scaffold --class ~.web.ElectricidadController --backingType ~.domain.Actuacion  --path electricidad
```

La idea es aplicar filtros en este nuevo controlador para luego mostrarlos en el mapa.

En el archivo *views/mapa/show.jspx*, pongo lo siguiente:

```
<layer:entity filterType="auto" id="l_es_ratowrs_geoportal2_domain_Actuacion" path="/electricidad" pk="id" z="user-managed">
            <layer:entity-field field="ubicacion" icon="glyphicon-home" iconLibrary="glyphicon" id="l_es_ratowrs_geoportal2_domain_Actuacion_ubicacion" markerColor="purple" z="8FKc5fLt7SAFzyuwUelU4X7zXuE="/>
        </layer:entity>
```

Sin embargo, en el filtro del mapa no me coge el controlador `Electricidad`, sino el de `Actuación`.

¿Alguna idea?